# Add custom background to Microsoft Login in React

Tags: reactjs, image, authentication, background

How can we add a background image to Microsoft login page in our React app?

Note : I'm using MSAL library and Microsoft API

Comment: Please provide some code so we can understand your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const MainContent = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  console.log({ isAuthenticated, loginRequest });
  useEffect(() => {
    // if (isAuthenticated) {
    instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    // }
  }, []);

Comment: This is the code I have used to open the Microsoft login page in my React application. I would like to customize the Microsoft login page with some background image. Can someone help me on doing that?